# Echo Permission Denied (Trying to use echo instead of ls command in shell script)

Tags: linux, shell-script, echo, openwrt, ash

I am trying to write a script and at some point i needed to list all the things in a directory and grep someting from that directory. I can't do it with ls. ls is not my guy to do it. So i tried to do ls' job with echo command instead , but it is giving me a permission denied error now.
You can see the script below :

```
#!/bin/sh
# Test for network connection

for interface in $(echo $(/sys/class/net/*) | grep -v lo);
do
  if [ "$(cat /sys/class/net/"$interface"/carrier)" = 1 ]; then
 OnLine=1;
 fi
done
if ! [ $OnLine ]; then echo "Not Online" > /dev/stderr;
 exit;
fi
```

And i am getting this error :

```
./carriercontrol.sh: line 10: /sys/class/net/apcli0: Permission denied
```

What can i do to complete this script ? Is there a way to get the listing of a directory and pipe it with something. Also even i could get rid of that permission then i think echo will cause more trouble to me.

**EDIT :** 
I tried to replace echo with find command , here is the results and errors.

```
#!/bin/sh


# Test for network conection
for interface in $(find /sys/class/net -mindepth 1 | grep -v lo);
do
  if [ "$(cat /sys/class/net/"$interface"/carrier)" = 1 ]; then
 OnLine=1;
 fi
done
if ! [ $OnLine ]; then echo "Not Online" > /dev/stderr;
 exit;
fi

cat: can't open '/sys/class/net//sys/class/net/ra0/carrier': No such file or directory
cat: can't open '/sys/class/net//sys/class/net/eth0/carrier': No such file or directory
cat: can't open '/sys/class/net//sys/class/net/br-lan/carrier': No such file or directory
cat: can't open '/sys/class/net//sys/class/net/eth0.1/carrier': No such file or directory
cat: can't open '/sys/class/net//sys/class/net/apcli1/carrier': No such file or directory
cat: can't open '/sys/class/net//sys/class/net/apcli0/carrier': No such file or directory
```

Comment: What about `find` command?

Comment: `$(/sys/class/net/*)` is a *command substitution* - it is trying to execute the files in `/sys/class/net`

Comment: In find command it is getting the directory itself for me. e.g. if i write find /sys/class/net/ it will bring me 
/sys/class/net/
/sys/class/net/ra0 
etc...  I don't want that /sys/class/net/ part

Comment: You could use a simple shell glob `for interface in /sys/class/net/*` and check for / exclude `lo` within the body of the loop

Comment: Can you be more spesific ?

Comment: Several questions that actually [address the goal](http://jdebp.info./FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html), and not the `echo` command, have already been asked here.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126009/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147030/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353179/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166659/5132 for starters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to want to query the `carrier` files under `/sys/class/net/*/` to see if there is at least one that indicates whether you're online or not (ignoring `*/lo/carrier`).

With a shell loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

online=0
for carrier in /sys/class/net/*/carrier; do
    case "$carrier" in
        */lo/carrier) continue ;;
    esac

    if read online <"$carrier" && [ "$online" -eq 1 ]; then
        break
    fi
done

if [ "$online" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo 'not online' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Using `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

online=0
for carrier in /sys/class/net/!(lo)/carrier; do
    if read online <"$carrier" && [ "$online" -eq 1 ]; then
        break
    fi
done

if [ "$online" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo 'not online' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Or, as a `bash` "almost-one-liner"

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

grep -qx 1 /sys/class/net/!(lo)/carrier || ! echo not online >&2
```

This last one assumes that the files hold a single digit `1` if that carrier is online and that there is no data, or at least no `1`, if it's not.

The loops above (using `read`) will read the first line only from each `carrier` file until a `1` is found.

---

The issue in your code is the command substitution `$(/sys/class/net/*)` which will try to execute the first matching filename as a command with the other matching filenames as arguments.

Also, the test `[ $OnLine ]` would be "true" whenever `$OnLine` is non-empty.  I'm not sure what the files that you parse contains if the carrier is not on-line, but even a zero would be taken as "true" here.

Comment: In sh version , you are checking the carrier after the for loop , so it is not working. When i try to implement it inside the for loop , i get bad number error.

Comment: @UgurAkgul I'm unfamiliar with these files. What do they contain if the carrier is not on-line?

Comment: It has a value like 1 , or 0. I don't know the reason behind bad number error. Carrier is telling us that , the network interface is up.

Comment: @UgurAkgul It would give that error if the thing it's reading is not a number. Try changing the `-eq` to `=` and `-ne` to `!=` to do string comparisons instead. (I'm leaving the screen for a couple of hours, but I'll sort it out properly later).

Comment: I tried to make things simple and after the if statement added an else statement. This is doing good so far. I'm sure i will be having problems about this.

Comment: @UgurAkgul I see what you're saying now. Why do you want to add an `else` inside the loop? There is nothing to be done in an `else` branch other than to continue with the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: I am using it with else now. It is doing it's work for now.

Answer (score 2):

How about these one-liners.  i.e. have `grep` specifically exclude the loopback.

**GNU grep**

Note : requires GNU `grep` [dated March 2001 or later](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/ChangeLog?id=bc35fa490562c6f52fd3db066ad421db6876c265#n510).  Specifically doesn't work on the BusyBox `grep` bundled in OpenWRT.

```
grep -q --exclude '/sys/class/net/lo/carrier' 1 /sys/class/net/*/carrier || echo "not online" >&2
```

**Solution suitable for older GNU grep versions and non-GNU grep**

e.g. BusyBox versions.

```
grep -x 1 /dev/null /sys/class/net/*/carrier|grep -qv /lo/ || ! echo 'not online' >&2
```

Comment: --exclude option doesn't working.

Comment: Old version of linux ?

Comment: openWRT distro of linux :)

Answer (score -2):

you can try to execute the above script in sudo mode

$sudo su

## "execute your script here"

Comment: I am running with root access all the time.