# Curl fails to download a file during start up

Tags: startup, curl

I am adding startup script in Ubuntu with update-rc.d.
My script says :

```
  #!/bin/bash

nohup curl -C - -o ~/Downloads/linuxmint-17-xfce-dvd-64bit.iso.part 'http://mirror.umd.edu/linuxmint/images/stable/17/linuxmint-17-xfce-dvd-64bit.iso'  
exit
```

Made it executable and added in /etc/init.d

Now when I run the script manually, it runs absolutely fine.

But after adding in startup, it does not start automatically.
It throws me with an error in nohup.out as below :

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

Is there anything more I need to check or what else option I can use to run the same script on startup.

```
root@amol-Lenovo-G570:~# ll /etc/rc2.d/ total 20 
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 7 20:24 ./ 
drwxr-xr-x 179 root root 12288 Nov 7 19:36 ../ 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Oct 23 12:38 K08vmware-USBArbitrator -> /etc/init.d/vmware-USBArbitrator* 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Sep 26 2012 S19postgresql -> ../init.d/postgresql*   
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Nov 7 20:24 S20download.sh -> ../init.d/download.sh*
```

where download.sh is the script I am running.

Comment: it look like your are trying to fetch before network layer is up. can you list /etc/rc2.d ? (or rcX.d where X is you run-level ? )

Comment: root@amol-Lenovo-G570:~# ll /etc/rc2.d/  

total 20  

drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov  7 20:24 ./  

drwxr-xr-x 179 root root 12288 Nov  7 19:36 ../  

lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    32 Oct 23 12:38 K08vmware-USBArbitrator -> /etc/init.d/vmware-USBArbitrator*  

lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    20 Sep 26  2012 S19postgresql -> ../init.d/postgresql*  

lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    21 Nov  7 20:24 S20download.sh -> ../init.d/download.sh*  
  

where download.sh is the script I am running.

Comment: `Couldn't connect to server` Your internet isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple. Your network isn't even up so:

```
Couldn't connect to server
```

I would create a upstart/systemd or a real sysv-init script with dependencies to the network.

There are several ways you can accomplish this:

- [With upstart](https://askubuntu.com/a/116130/169736)
- [With systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126009/41104)
- [Sysv init scripts](http://www.slackware.com/config/init.php) are in many ways more complicated, but if you want portability, it may be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `--retry 5 --retry-max-time 120` and it'll eventually work just fine.