# Start radio with systemd service

Tags: boot, systemd, startup, services, daemon

On a headless RaspberryPi, I would like to automatically start radio on boot, without any human action. I have written this file as `/etc/systemd/system/radio.service` :

```
[Unit]
Description=Radio
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mplayer http://audio.scdn.arkena.com/11016/fip-midfi128.mp3 &
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work: after boot, doing `systemctl status radio` shows :

> Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/radio.service; disabled)
>     Active: inactive (dead)

I think the `Wants` and `After` are necessary because an "up" network is required, [as described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126146/59989).

**Should I change `Type` or `RemainAfterExit`? Or remove the `&` at the end of `ExecStart`? Something else?**

---

Comment: Did you enable the service? `systemctl enable radio`. Does it start with `systemctl start radio`?

Comment: @Thomas It works when I manually `systemctl start radio`. But when I reboot, it doesn't start automatically. Instead the status shows `Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/radio.service; disabled) Active: inactive (dead)`.

Comment: Ohhhhh that's true, that's the answer! I forgot this step. I'll accept it if you copy paste as an answer! By the way, Should I change Type or RemainAfterExit? Or remove the & at the end of ExecStart for "best practice"?

Comment: I think you do not need the `&` at the end of the binary. And I also would leave `RemainAfterExit=no` which is the default. I'd rather would change to `Type=Simple`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, being able to start the service manually sounds good. You also have to  enable the service with `systemctl enable radio`?
From the `systemctl status radio` it looks like the service is not enabled and thus doesn't start.