# how to adjust the boot sequence using systemd

Tags: systemd, postfix

I need to send email using postfix as server once wifi has received IP address (based on dhcpcd). It seems that `systemd` by default boot postfix before wifi (wlan0) is ready. The consequence associated with this is that postfix failed to run in background and email can not be sent, successfully. However, if I run the following script (namely **abc.sh**) on boot, email can definitely get through:

```
sleep 60
systemctl restart postfix
echo 'email content' | mail -s 'titile' mailaccount@gmail.com
```

The service file associated with **abc.sh** is given below:

```
[Unit]
Description=pptp_setup
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/pi/script/abc.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note that **sleep 60** and **systemctl restart postfix** is the trick to ensure the email is sent. if only **sleep 60** is applied without restarting postfix, the email still can not send through as postfix is not booted properly initially ( as mentioned above, it may get loaded before receiving an IP). Also If only postfix is restarted without sleep for 60 seconds, the postfix reboot still would still fail, even     [**Requires=network-online.target** and    **After=network-online.target**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126009/cause-a-script-to-execute-after-networking-has-started) have been applied in the service file.

My question is how to set postfix correctly so that it gets booted after wifi has received ip address.

Answer (score 2):

It is ever-green problem with `systemd`, as discussed many times on many [places](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1116538). With "slow network" activation, your best chance is probably `IP_FREEBIND`. You can't modify that for postfix-only, but system-wide using:

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_nonlocal_bind
```

under the root account. It is well-described in manual page for [`ip(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html).

Comment: `systemd` certainly has its flaws, but this particular issue isn't entirely its fault. What's going wrong here is that the unit file that handles setting up networking returns 'all done!' before it's actually finished. If someone using `sysvinit` with a networking script that backgrounded the call to `dhcpcd` you could potentially run into the same problem if it got to the postfix launch before dhcpcd actually finished; it'd just be less *likely* because of the linear boot sequence.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issues when deploying Ubuntu 16.10 to a new MiniPC (opposed to Ubuntu 14.x that worked fine).

I have finally found an automated solution for this: enable the NetworkManager-wait-online.service and deploy a custom script that restarts the postfix service +-5 minutes after the machine has booted (assuming that the wireless connection is active by then).

A. Enable this.
It is a generic approach that might be beneficial for other service than Postfix as well so I keep it in the script.

`systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service; systemctl status NetworkManager-wait-online.service;`

B. Add a customer Systemd timer + service
@info The timer will start ONCE, {x} minutes after the machine was booted.

`nano /etc/systemd/system/mjd-restart-postfix-after-wlan-connected.timer
    [Unit]
    Description=(timer)mjd-restart-postfix-after-wlan-connected
    [Timer]
    OnBootSec=5min
    [Install]
    WantedBy=timers.target`


`` nano /etc/systemd/system/mjd-restart-postfix-after-wlan-connected.service
    [Unit]
    Description=mjd-restart-postfix-after-wlan-connected
    [Service]
    Type=oneshot
    ExecStart=/bin/sh -ec "systemctl restart postfix; systemctl status postfix; uname -a | /usr/bin/mailx -s \"Server  (`hostname`): postfix was restarted.\" youremail@gmail.com" ``

`MYUNIT=mjd-restart-postfix-after-wlan-connected
MYTIMER=${MYUNIT}.timer
systemctl enable ${MYTIMER};  systemctl status ${MYTIMER}; 
systemctl list-units --all | grep "${MYUNIT}"
systemctl status ${MYUNIT}`

C. Restart
`reboot`
# wait 5 minutes

D. Check

`MYUNIT=mjd-restart-postfix-after-wlan-connected
MYTIMER=${MYUNIT}.timer
systemctl status ${MYTIMER}`

If the contents of these 2 config files (one of Resolve and one of Postfix) are not the same then the issue is PROBLEMATIC (Postfix started before LAN/WLAN gets connected).
cat /etc/resolv.conf
cat /var/spool/postfix/etc/resolv.conf

E. Info
@doc https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/postfix/+bug/1519331
@doc https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers
@doc qshape deferred
@doc cat /var/log/syslog | egrep "NetworkManager|postfix"