# Why isn't my systemd service waiting for the network?

Tags: networking, systemd

Per [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126009/cause-a-script-to-execute-after-networking-has-started) question and its answers, I've added the following to my service file:

```
Wants=network-online.target
After=docker.service network.target network-online.target
```

I've also run:

```
systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

And yet my `ExecStartPre` task which uses `git pull origin master` still fails because of what appears to be a connectivity issue.

```
Mar 22 16:17:21 COMPUTER git[1983]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known
Mar 22 16:17:21 COMPUTER git[1983]: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Am I missing something obvious? Is there another service I need to wait for in order to use `git pull`? (In case it's relevant, I'm using Ubuntu 16.10 and systemd 231.)

Comment: What distribution are you using? There is no guarantee that your distribution's own networking units have correct dependencies w/r/t `network-online.target`.    Possibly you will need to make your unit `After=NetworkManager.service` (or `After=NetworkManager-wait-online.service`).

Comment: @larsks Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: Does the service work if you start it after boot?

Comment: @Centimane Yes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First step is to determine if you're using `NetworkManager` or `systemd-networkd`. Enable `wait-online` for the one you are using (assuming `systemd-networkd` for this example):

```
systemctl enable systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

Have your service start after the `wait-online` service:

```
[Unit]
...
After=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
Requires=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

(requires is a stricter variant of `wants`, in this case it seems like you want the hard dependency).

This should cause your service to start after the network is guaranteed up.

---

Alternatively (or in conjunction with the previous solution) you can configure the service to restart when it fails using the `Restart=` flag:

```
[Service]
...
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
```

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=

This might be the better method, because it wont slow your boot (https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/#cutthecraphowdoimakenetwork.targetworkforme - using `wait-online` is liable to slow your boot-time considerably), but if you're worried about what the service might do when it fails, go for option 1 or both.

Comment: Should be pinned somewhere. Really helpful even if 2 years old. Thank you.