# Sending and receiving simple signals between computers?

Tags: shell-script, networking

I have a RaspberryPi, running the standard Pi distro, and a computer running Linux 16.04 in the same local network with fixed IP adresses. The Pi is used to wake the computer by sending a Wake-on-Lan package and then tunnelling onto the computer via SSH.

Is there an easy and simple way for the computer to send a message to the Pi, which the Pi then interprets as the computer having started up succesfully and being reachable?

I already have set up a system where the Pi is continuously pinging the computer until it gets a response, but I specificly want to have the computer  message the Pi and not the Pi checking up on the computer.

Comment: Just put something like `echo foo | nc <pi ip address> <port>` into /etc/rc.local on computer, and have pi listen on the given port for messages in separate script   or even background. You could then use `wait` from script to know when background task finished.

Comment: And how would I set up the Pi to listen for that ping?

Comment: I've put that as an answer in more details. General idea is that you already have `nc` tool for sending packets and testing connection with most *nix systems, and it's easy to make a simpke server-client type of thing with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nc` - simplest method.

On computer( assuming it is a *nix system) :  put `( echo "computer is up" | nc 192.168.0.123   6677 ) &` into `/etc/rc.local`. The `(...) &` spawns background shell to prevent the rc.local script from blocking other things from execution while computer boots. Assume 192.68.0.123 is your Pi's IP address on same network as computer .

On Pi, have a process listening on port 6677 with `nc -l 6677` after whatever command you're using to send wake on LAN signal.  By default `nc` terminates once the sending side closed the connection ( which should happen after all bytes of "computer is up" string have been sent ). So you could do something like

```
netreply=$( nc -l 6677)
case $netreply in
     "computer is up") echo "All good" ;;
     *)  echo some boo-boo happened ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out and see if that works.

Comment: I'm not sure `rc.local` works very well with `systemd`  ... a more universal solution for most current Linux distros is to use a systemd service file that waits until the network interface is up and running...  like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126009/cause-a-script-to-execute-after-networking-has-started/126062#126062)

Comment: @RubberStamp `rc.local` works with systemd and there is `rc-local.service` which executes `/etc/rc.local` script. See https://askubuntu.com/a/919598/295286  Can you explain what exactly you mean by "not sure ...works very well" part ? Even though I agree it'd be nicer to have an actual service made, `/etc/rc.local` is perfectly fine alternative.

Comment: Some distros may not include (or enable) the rc.local service in the default configuration. My understanding is that the rc.local systemd service runs after the network is up and running anyway.  So, why not just put the messaging script its own service file for easy visibility and uniformity?  ... I guess the point was, it's possible that a given Linux distro will not automatically run rc.local ....

Comment: @RubberStamp Fair enough. But if it's not enabled by default nothing stops us from enabling that service. But sure, it may be a viable alternative for visibility/uniformity to have it's own service.

Comment: Your suggestion did indeed work! Now, since my computer has the bad habit of starting itself without me actually wanting it to, can I implement a service on the Pi that is permamently listening for the computer to wake up and respond appropriately (I already have shutdown script, I just need a way to detect the computer starting), that can be stopped when I want to start the computer?

Comment: @UmBottesWillen  Glad I could help. The `nc` command has `-k` switch which would make it to stay listening on the port for new connections So `nc -k -l 6677` is probably what you want. Output from that probably could be piped to something else, like `nc -k -l 6677 | while IFS= read -r line; do  printf  "Received message: %s" "$line" ; done`  And in that command you could replace `printf` with whatever you want the Pi to do.

Comment: Sorry for the late addendum, for now everything has worked out quite well. While I do struggle to get the service running, I'm confident that I'll figure that one out. Now, my last, tiny question for you would be if I can specify a source Ip adress for `nc -l` to listen for and to disregard connections made from any other IP adresses.

Comment: @UmBottesWillen I think what you need is `-v` flag to give verbose output from `nc`. It should report what address connected to the port, but you'll have to parse it later with other tools, such as `awk` maybe, but bash's basic `case` statement could work too. If you need specific parsing, best idea would be to ask a new question as we're kinda going out of scope of this question by now.